# How to create a border in Photoshop that's not blurry

Tags: adobe-photoshop, border, stroke

I'm trying to create a border around an area but the way I'm doing it it always is blurry.

What I do is create a rectangle selection then go to Select > Modify > Border > 1px > OK > Fill.

It looks like it's a blurry 3 px.

Comment: Which version of Photoshop?

Comment: ............CS5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting and then `Edit > Stroke... > 1px > OK`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your rectangle selection starting with a feather? Make sure the "Feather" for your rectangle selection is "0px".

Comment: I've been caught by that before but I triple checked it to make sure.